# Scrollview not scrolling till end when keyboard is up in samsung tablet

Tags: android, scrollview, tablet

In my application, there is activity it has scrollview and set of EditText fields inside scrollview.

Below is the code i am using.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/light_gray"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="10dp">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bg_light_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/a"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email"
            />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/b"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="UserName"
             />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/c"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Pwd" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/d"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Conf pwd" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/e"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Other" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/f"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Other1"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/g"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Other2" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/h"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Other3" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/i"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Other4" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/j"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Other5" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The issue here in landscape mode when keyboard up, scrollview is able to scroll till few EditText fields and it stops there and it not scrolling till end.

I have tried android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" and "adjustPan" also, but no luck.

**Can some suggest how to allow the scrollview to scroll till end when keyboard shown?. Please find attached screenshots**

[image: full page][image: keyboard up][image: Maximum scrolling]

Answer (score 0):

The `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` added to the `<actvity>` in the manifest should do the trick. Please try to set `adjustResize` soft input mode and at the same time, change your parent `<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"`. The `adjustResize` resizes the space available for a window of your app, however in order to notice that changed amount of parent space - your layout should observe that, I home the `match_parent` will help.

Comment: Thank you for help. Applied but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout height "wrap_content" to "match_parent" and make  android:fillViewport="true" in your Scrollview in xml file.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
 // Do your stubs
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Applied but no luck